# Javascript reverse engineering: Convert html table to string/text

Tags: javascript, html, string, html-table

Currently I have a table variable which I want to get its table content in this way: `<table><tr></tr></table>` instead of getting a Javascript object. Is there a solution to finding a method that could do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try [innerHTML](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php).

Answer (score 1):

This assumes your table is the only table on the page.  If this is not the case, give it a unique ID (such as `tableID`) and reference using `getElementsById("tableID")`.

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var firstTable = tables[0];
var tableAttr = firstTable.attributes;
// get the tag name 'table', and set it lower case since JS will make it all caps
var tableString = "<" + firstTable.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ">";
// get the tag attributes
for(var i = 0; i < tableAttr.length; i++) {
    tableString += " " + tableAttr[i].name + "='" + tableAttr[i].value + "'";
}

// use innerHTML to get the contents of the table, then close the tag
tableString += firstTable.innerHTML + "</" +
    firstTable.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ">";

// table string will have the appropriate content
```

You can [see this in action in a short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ybb2L/1/).

The pertinent things to learn are:

- getElementsByTagName - get DOM elements by their tag name
- attributes - a DOM property that gets an attributes array
- innerHTML - gets a string of the HTML inside any DOM object
- nodeName - gets the name of any DOM object

If you get into using a framework, [jquery's](http://jquery.com/) [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method and the [getAttributes](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes) plugin would potentially also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try following code...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sample_function(){
            alert(document.getElementById('div_first').innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div_first">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
    <button onclick="sample_function()">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```